# Is there a broadcast/intent when Android OS update happens?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, ota

I was looking for a hook, like action intent, which can call my app (having a service), when an OS update has happened. (The boot when OS update has happened.)

I checked the standard action content on the Android website, but couldn't find one which I can use directly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is no special version of `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` or other `Intent` actions that is unique to a reboot after an OS upgrade.

When your service gets control for any reason, compare the current `Build` information to some cached copy that you maintain, to see if there is a difference that matters to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can check firmware version by `Build.RADIO` or `Build.getRadioVersion()` on each system reboot to find out if update occured.